# How did this awful code completely clobber a JS file in an IOS phonegap/cordova app?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webview

Sigh...

```
var dcCnt = 0;
(function deviceCheck(){
    if(!device || dcCnt +=1 >= 25){
        if(dcCnt >=25){
            alert('device object load timed out');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert('device loaded after deviceready');
            return true;
        }
        setTimeout( deviceCheck, 200);
    }
});
```

Yes, yes, so clearly `if(!device dcCnt+=1 || dcCnt += 1 >= 25)` was going to be a problem. The original version of this monstrosity just had () parens after it to set the whole thing off. It was just debug code to try and sort out an issue where I wasn't getting the device object for some reason (ultimately that turned out to be a hoisted var in an if statement - I should have known better). It didn't appear to work after I tweaked at one point and I just killed the action parens with the inent to look into it later.

But here's the thing. In spite of never being called, this code, when not commented out turned an entire JS file into a gaping black hole in iOS from which no return uh... could be returned. I could fire scripts before and after the linked file. But no alert worked at the beginning or the end. Try/Catch statements did absolutely nothing. It was like the entire file just disappeared.

Android, of course, worked fine. 'use strict' was in play but it doesn't seem to matter to ios or android. Works fine in Chrome too if you don't try to fire it. So what the hell happened?

Comment: Your `setTimeout( deviceCheck, 200);` will never be reached. And the `deviceCheck` is never invoked without the `()`.

Comment: I'm aware it's broken and doesn't work. What's amazing to me is the impact it had on the rest of the js file it was in when consumed by whatever interpreter iOS's webview runs.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. Your descriptions of the issue, while colorful, aren't entirely clear.

Comment: It does nothing. It was never called. Yet when present in the JS file absolutely nothing in that file worked. Even try/catch wrapping all the JS was failing to fire simple alerts.

Comment: So there's more to the JS file than just this. And you're getting no errors, but it still causes it to fail. Does it fix it if you change this `dcCnt +=1 >= 25` to this `(dcCnt +=1) >= 25`?

Comment: That fixes the syntax error when you fire (and hit an infinite loop no doubt if !device is true). Removing the entire silly thing allows the file to work fine. I'll try fixing that. I'm thinking maybe the parser wanting to assign everything on the right of that += for the rest of page or something. I'll try that when I get chance. Thx for the suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting different interpretations of when the error should be thrown when running in Chrome vs Firefox. *(I don't have mobile devices to test right now).* Chrome allows it to parse, and throws a ReferenceError at runtime, while Firefox throws the same error immediately, which would seem odd for a ReferenceError, but certainly more useful. Just not sure why they don't call it a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that WebKit couldn't parse the js file, most likely due to something not being commented out correctly.

Throw it in an iOS Simulator and run Safari's Web Inspector on the simulator. You'll probably see a js syntax error.

As for why it runs on Android and not iOS... Some browsers are more finicky than others I guess.

Comment: There was a blend of /* */ and regEx in the same file but pretty sure they were cleanly separated and I removed all /**/ comments at one point with no results.

Comment: 'Pretty sure' will one day be the death of us all. The only way to truly know is to use the Web Inspector.

Comment: There was a syntax error. It's that += on the right side of the || operator. Chrome sees that when you try to fire it. But it was never fired. I guess the parser just saw that and quit.

Comment: Never got around to verifying this before the project was done but this looks to be the most likely culprit so I'll make this the answer.